# Why android deeplink didn't jump to the correct activity？

Tags: android

I have two apps, click the button in app A will jump to app B due to deeplink. And in app B, there are two activities including SplashActivity and MainActivity, where I set the intent filter in SplashActivity that deeplink will bring it to in app B when the button in app A is clicked. And it worked fine for most time.

However, here is the situation. I open app A, click the button, and jump to app B's SplashActivity, which start MainActivity in a while and then finish itself. Till now it works fine, however, when I switch front app to app A, which means app B is in background now, and then I click the button again in the app A. This time it doesn't jump to SplashActivity(onCreate() and onResume() of app B are not called), but to MainActivity by calling it's onResume() callback, and the intent.data, which is sent from app A, is find to be null.

So why the deeplink didn't bring the app to the expected activity in the situation above? Begging for any answer!

Answer (score 1):

When opening the deeplink while app is in background, doesn't launch the new app instead it open the current instance of the app. This is to avoid multiple instances of the same app.
In the manifest file, you need to add the follow to your main activity.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

With this, if an instance of activity already exists at the top of the current task, no new instance will be created because it will fire off an `onNewIntent()` method instead of creating a new object.
You can fetch and handle your intent data in `onNewIntent()`

Comment: Actually it's already set to be singleTask under the problem

Comment: You should be getting deeplink data in onNewIntent()

Comment: I have tried so, but the onNewIntent() was not called in the last situation above

Comment: Can you edit the query and and a bit of code so that we can get an idea of what are you trying to do